# Best way to filter (search engine) in query

Tags: laravel, postgresql, elasticsearch, search, eloquent

Currently i have a table (car_brands) of list of cars brands (honda,toyota,bmw,mercedes benz,etc..) and i have a title which user will key in for example `mercedes benz e 230`, so I would like to get the input by user can search through to get the brand from the car_brands table. Whats the best way for me to do it and how can i optimized it so that it will run faster and get better result.

Current code is

```
$user_input = 'mercedes benz e 230';
CarBrand::where('name', 'ilike', '%' . $user_input . '%')->first();
```

[image]

and so on for the table result..

Comment: did you get a chance to look at my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define, your `car_brand` as keyword and search after, filtering on `car_brand` field, this would:

1. Reduce the documents to search only in a specific brand as per your requirement and fewer document to search means, faster search.
2. Filters are cached in Elasticsearch, so next time again when you filter the same term example `mercedes`, it would get from the cache, which would be quite fast as compare to again filtering the data.

### Index def

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "brand": {
                "type": "keyword" --> note
            },
            "title": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Index sample doc

```
{
    "title" : "mercedes benz e 330",
    "brand" : "mercedes"
}

{
    "title" : "fortuner",
    "brand" : "toyota"
}
```

### Search query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "title": "mercedes benz e 330"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "brand": "Mercedes" --> filter `Mercedes` brand and then do search
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

### Result

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "so_query_car",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 1.2401118,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "mercedes benz e 330",
                    "brand": "mercedes"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Hi, but how do i write it in laravel ? haha

Comment: Another think is that the car brand is dynamic so its hard to filter as i do not know the values the user will put in. they might just enter the model followed by the brand

Comment: @DaljitSingh, 1) in your question you didn't mention that car brand can be dynamic 2) even if its dynamic, using the client, you can create a proper query to include all the car_brands and I know how to do it using java client not laravel and if you understand the concept and using REST API able to get the expected results , then you can write code later on .